# How to use SELECT clause inside SET clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to clear values in all columns except a couple of columns in a table. I can think of retrieving all column names except those two using following query

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='accountuser' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN('firstname', 'lastname');

UPDATE accountuser
SET ??
WHERE accountuserid=?;
```

I am not sure how to use column name from a result set inside `SET` clause.

Other ways I could think of is to construct the query at the application level by running both queries separately or explicitly pass all the column names but it becomes non-deterministic when the table changes.

**UPDATE**:

The scenario where this query will be used is, when a user is deleted in the application, all columns for that user are cleared except first name and last name so that any references to the deleted user in the application will still exist, like comments in threads etc. We use Spring JDBC with a plain text file that contains all SQL queries. So I would like this in a single query if possible and if not, would like to construct the query at application level.

Comment: you can't really use the result of one query as a keyword/identifier in another query directly. you CAN build a new query string and then execute it, e.g. ` @sql = concat('update .... set ', @somevar, '=someval' ); exec@sql;`

Comment: Are you open to the idea of creating a temporary table and an entirely new table with the same name as the old one?

Comment: Do you dynamically create the tables in your application too?  In my experience this points to a data model that is broken.  You shouldn't have to do this or you should be able to code the column list without expecting it to change.  If this does not make sense then show me the schema you are using and I will explain for your specific case.

Comment: I do not dynamically create the tables. This is just in case if a developer who adds a new column in user table missed to update this query with new column name, then there will be information in the user table even after the user is deleted.

Comment: Do you want to set NULL in those columns?

Comment: @1000111 Yes,  want to set null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `NULL` in those columns:

```
SET @sql := '';

SELECT 
CONCAT('UPDATE accountuser SET ',GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,'= NULL'),' WHERE accountuser = ', PUT_ACCOUNTUSER_ID_HERE)
INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('firstname','lastname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

**Note:** Include the `primary key column` in the `NOT IN` clause. Otherwise it will be set `NULL` too.